# Is it possible to map this kind of url to my controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following controller:

```
public class DispatchController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to map route (or something else) so that url like this one

`https://my-website.com/abcd`

properly resolve to my `Dispatch` controller, `Index` action and `abcd` as a value of `id` parameter?

I have tried the following routes:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "dispatch1",
                template: "{controller=Dispatch}/{action=Index}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "dispatch2",
                template: "{controller=Dispatch}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name : "areas",
                template : "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
```

`https://my-website.com` works fine, resolves fine (id is null)

`https://my-website.com/abcd` does not work, does not resolve (404)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Route` attribute.

```cs
[Route("{id}")]
public class DispatchController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using conventional [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2) (instead of attribute based routing), you can register the route below.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "id-only",
    template: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Dispatch", action = "Index" }
    );
```

Beware of the order of registration; in your case it should look like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "dispatch1",
    template: "{controller=Dispatch}/{action=Index}");
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "dispatch2",
    template: "{controller=Dispatch}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
routes.MapRoute(
    name : "areas",
    template : "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"   
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "id-only",
    template: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Dispatch", action = "Index" }
    );
```

---

Note that you can't combine attribute based routing and conventional routing 
within the same `Controller`.
From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#mixed-routing-attribute-routing-vs-conventional-routing):

> Actions are either conventionally routed or attribute routed.
>   Placing a route on the controller or the action makes it attribute routed.
>   Actions that define attribute routes cannot be reached through the conventional routes and vice-versa. Any route attribute on the controller makes all actions in the controller attribute routed.